# Convert mm/dd/yyy to mysql format

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

1. I have a form with a date field.
2. I select a date using a jquery datepicker. The format is mm/dd/yyyy.
3. The date inserts into the db like 0000-00-00.
4. When I use die($startdate); This outputs the correct date in the correct format when uncommented.

**db type:** date

**Code:**

```
$startdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['startdate']));
  //die($startdate); //<--outputs the correct date in the correct format when uncommented.

  try {

 $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO table (firstname,lastname,startdate) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :startdate)');
  $stmt->execute(array(
    ':firstname' => $_POST['firstname'],
    ':lastname' => $_POST['lastname'],
    ':startdate' => $_POST['startdate'],

   ));

  }
```

I also tried

```
$startdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['startdate']));
```

in the try{} but doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

This is to John Conde.  I believe it's quite simple on how this is different and why it's not a duplicate.  If you didn't notice there was an "ERROR" in my code.  I needed help finding the issue. Marc found it and now it works.  I still wonder why this is so difficult to understand.

Comment: This question has been asked multiple times on stackoverflow. Please search it, you will definitely find your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spot the difference:

```
$startdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['startdate']));
^^^^^^^^^^

    ':startdate' => $_POST['startdate'],
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You convert the date properly, but then use the original un-converted version in the query.

Comment: Thanks Marc.   I see they are the same and I'm very new to this.  I'm assuming $startdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['startdate']));  should be something like $startdatediff = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['startdate']));  ?   I did just that but db still showing 0000-00-00

Comment: For those of you at my level Marc means this  ':startdate' => $startdate .  It's working now.